# What is the difference between Dhithi (view) and Panna (wisdom)?

Tags: the-buddha

What is the difference between Dhithi (view) and Panna (wisdom)?
According to Buddhism the teaching of other religions considered views.
However, people who follow those religions think that they have wisdom.
How can we differentiate views from wisdom?

Answer (score 3):

Panna is understanding, knowledge, wisdom, insight. Panna is always correct.

Ditthi is simply view. Ditthi can be either right(Samma-ditthi) or wrong(Micca-ditti).

Samma-ditthi has 2 levels:

1. The right view caused by faith in another's teaching and/or faith in personal feelings,perceptions and reasoning.

   ex: having the view that rebirth is true without actually knowing and without knowing the nature of phenomena
2. The right view caused by Panna

   ex: having the view that rebirth is true by direct knowledge and/or by inference(through understanding of how phenomena arise).

Micca-ditthi has nothing to do with Panna. It is caused by ignorance and the faith in someone else's false teachings or the faith in one's own feelings, perceptions and false reasoning.

ex: believing that death is the end regardless of one's mental conditioning

Comment: If you are abhidhamma student, wrong ditthi is wrong panna in dhammasangini. It is a synonym for each other. If you can read pali, I will send you  evidences.

Comment: The word maybe used in the sense of "false knowledge". Did you see a place where Micca-ditthi is referred to with just  the word 'Panna'?

Comment: Dhammacakkappavattanasuttam synonym: "**cakkhum** udapadi **nanam** udapadi **panna** udapadi vijja udapadi aloko udapadi." Another in the same sutta: "evam tiparivattam tvadasakaram yathabhutam **nanadassanam** suvisuddham ahosi." So, I often said tipitaka pali reciting and memorizing is very important and seriously require.

Comment: My question is where does it say Panna = Micca-ditthi ?

Comment: In Abhidhammapitaka Dhammasangini akusalacittuppadakanda lobhaditthigatasampayutta. Also, you can notice it yourself, too. While you recite tipitaka pali.

Comment: Can you share the exact quote?

Comment: Oh! this is very interesting case that I never notice that tipitaka obviously doesn't has  micchā-paññā, even if in abhidhamma or K.N. Paṭi. However,  in conclusion of K.N. Paṭi.,  conclusion of Abh.Dha. Akusalacitta. and commentary of Abh.Dha. Akusalacitta, there are acceptation of existence of micchā-paññā, **but the commentary seem to say "micchā-paññā is exist, but never found in mula-pali"**. Then I searching for the real reason through the night, but still not found.. I guess that it maybe because of p-upasagga. Overall, thank you verymuch for new knowledge.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

**Right, Sammā** =  possible to happen in **reality cause and effect rules**.

**Wrong, Sammā** =  impossible to happen in **reality cause and effect rules**.

**Diṭṭhi** = attitude element of mind that collecting several right/wrong aspects of knowledge.

**Paññā** = learning element of mind that learning several right/wrong aspects of knowledge.

*When you learning knowledge, is while you collecting knowledge.*

**So, Diṭṭhi = Paññā.**

Therefore, Sammā**Diṭṭhi** = the attitude element of mind  that collecting **several aspects** of learning knowledge,   that is right, possible to happen in **cause and effect rules**, such as paṭiccasamuppāda, paṭṭhāna, or 10 sammādiṭṭhi, etc. = Sammap**Paññā** = The learning element of mind that learning **several aspects** of learning knowledge, that is right, possible to happen in **cause and effect rules**, such as paṭiccasamuppāda, paṭṭhāna, or 10 sammādiṭṭhi, etc.

*See: abhidhamma such as ñāṇavibhaṅga, and understanding chapter of part of purification.*

Edited: tipitaka doesn't use "micchā-paññā" word, even if in abhidhamma or K.N. Paṭi. However,  in conclusion of K.N. Paṭi.,  conclusion of Abh.Dha. Akusalacitta. and commentary of Abh.Dha. Akusalacittuppādakaṇḍa, there are acceptations of existence of micchā-paññā, **but the commentary just seem to say "micchā-paññā is exist, but never found in mula-pali"**. I searching for the real reason through the night for that why tipitaka doesn't use "micchā-paññā", but I still not found. I guess that it maybe because of pa-upasagga. Overall, thank you, **@Sankha Kulathantille** very much for new knowledge.

Comment: >SammapPaññā> Wow! never thought about it.

Comment: I could not find this word in Pali dictionary.

Comment: Recite anattalakkhana sutta pali. Sammappanna is in side that sutta. https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.nymo.html

Answer (score -2):

Dhithi means thought, idea. In pali it means dogma; theory; belief.

Panna means wise, endowed with knowledge, insight.

Dhithi is fabricated by the fabricated self.

Panna is not fabricated.

To differentiate dhithi from panna you have to know how dhithi arises, what is its cause and what is its cessation.

Once you know this, dhithi can cease and panna is attained.

Then you can easily differentiate between the two.

**FURTHER READING:**

Why panna is not fabricated?

When you meditate and perception ceases, and even the state of neither-perception-nor-non-perception ceases, and even that same cessation ceases, and all perception ceases, so that even meditation itself ceases ... that is reality.

When observation of reality arises, that "observation of reality" is a fabrication, a not truth. Nonetheless, even though that "observation of reality" is a fabrication, a not truth, it really is not a fabrication, it is truth, it is panna.

When that "observation of reality" is put into words, these "words" are fabrications, not truths. Nonetheless, even though these "words" are fabrications, not truths, they really are not fabrications, they are truths, they are panna.

When "observation of reality" arises and this "observation of reality" is described with "words", even though this "observation of reality" and the "words describing reality" are fabrications, not truths, they really are not fabrications, they are truth, they are panna.

"Observation of reality" and "words describing reality" can be called "panna". Nonetheless, even though this "panna" is a fabrication, not truth, it really is not a fabrication, it is truth, it is panna.

When a person has panna, what is fabricated is not truth, but since it is being fabricated with panna, that which is fabricated is not a fabrication, it is truth.

Comment: Can an like Nyom Beginner provide a serious source for the statement "Panna is not fabricated."?

Comment: @Samana No serious source available. But it's logical: Panna is truth. How can truth be fabricated? It cannot. Truth is truth. It cannot be fabricated.

Comment: It's not the talk about nibbana here, Beginner, but - in you words - "having truth" (e.g. wisdom). As the Buddha adviced: Don't go after logical conjunctions. Even the realm, the state of Neither-perception-nor-non-perception1 is fabricated.

Comment: @Samana You are right. I updated the answer to see what I meant with "Panna is not fabricated".

Comment: Looks better Nyom Beginner and transports well that the [path actually has an Essence](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/beyond_en.html#ch8) in regard of this importand issue: liberation.. Sadhu for effort to try to bend it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I'm asking because I want to know where the answer must be improved.